# how to send ArrayList from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to send an ArrayList from jsp to Servlet and retrive that ArrayList in Servlet. 
I am using `form action=myServlet` and sending ArrayList as an hidden parameter. 
But it is not working.

How to send arrayList from JSP to Servlet. Is it possiple

Comment: How are you using arrayList as hidden parameter? can you show code? You need to pass a request attribute, not the parameter. Parameters can only be strings

Comment: Thank You Prasad Kharkar. Will you please tell me how to pass request attribute from jsp to Servlet.

Comment: I need. I am showing my reports in html doc. then on that same page i am giving another button pdf.  on clicking that button a servlet is called which has code to show report in pdf format. the data to display should be passed to srvlet.

Comment: If you need to send those data to servlet for PDF report, then better set that arraylist into session and use that session in that servlet.Why you are sending the data from servlet to jsp then from jsp to servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to send arrayList from JSP to Servlet. Is it possiple

Yes definitely it is possible, you need to

- Populate the arrayList object in the request object.
- Retrieve the list in servlet.

As you have not provided information whether you are using scriptlets or jstl, I'm assuming the scriptlets.

In your JSP,

```
 request.setAttribute("arrayList", yourListObject);
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("servletUrlPattern");
 rd.forward(request, response);
```

In your servlet, you can access the list using

```
 List yourList = (List)request.getAttribute("arrayList");
```

To call the servlet from your JSP file,

```
 <form action = "yourServletUrl" method = "POST">
    //everything in the form here.
     <input type = "submit" name = "submit">
 </form>
```

After pressing submit button, you will be able to get your jsp data into it.

Comment: Thanks Prasad. Let me try this.

Comment: yeap, that should work +1

Comment: I want to do all this on a button click.

Comment: On button click, you call the servlet,

Comment: yaa. but how? I am not getting that only.

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: ok. I was assuming that  on rd.forward() will pass the control.