# Send ArrayList from a JSP page to servlet when submitting a form

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to retrieve the `ArrayList` from a JSP page to servlet when submitting the form on the JSP page. I am trying following code:

Code of `Pass.jsp` is:

```
<form action="GetListServlet">
<%
    ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
    al.add("Naman");
    al.add("Gupta");
    request.setAttribute("allnames", al); 
%>
<input type="submit" value="Show List"></form>
```

`doGet()` method of `GetListServlet` is :-

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    ArrayList al=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("allnames");
    System.out.print(al.get(0));
}
```

But I am getting `NullPointerException at System.out.print(al.get(0))`.

Can anyone tell me how can I get arraylist of jsp page on the servlet page ?

Comment: Try this
[link][1]. This gives a better solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988612/how-to-send-arraylist-from-jsp-to-servlet

Comment: I think you have a general misconception of what `request` is. You should solve this problem in plain HTML and then attempt to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to *not* store your array into response and send it back to the server. Instead, store your list into session using `session.setAttribute("allnames", al);` and obtain it in similar way: `ArrayList al=(ArrayList)request.getSession().getAttribute("allnames");`. You don't have to send the array to the client and back again.

But if you really want to, you can store the array as list of hidden HTML input fields and then obtain them from servlet using `String[] al=request.getParameterValues('allnames');`.

Comment: Sorry for the down vote, but adding session here is going to make it more confusing and introduce a new set of problems.

Comment: Please can you elaborate why using a session is confusing and what's wrong with hidden form fields and obtaining all values for one parameter? The question is obviously about passing a list of data from one request to another.